# Sorting custom taxonomy parent in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, sorting, parent, taxonomy

The array from my taxonomy query is not sorted by parent. Instead it is sorted alphabetically.

So I have the following custom listing,

- Name
- Email
- - Country
- - - State
- - - - City

-- Country is a custom taxonomy (the parent).

--- State would be the child.

---- City would be the child of the child.

I have the following code query running,

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
                        'post_type' => 'listings',
                        'taxonomy' => 'listings_region',
                        'parent' => 0,
                        'orderby' => 'parent',
                        'post__in' => $post_ids,
                        'fields' => 'ids',
                    ) );
```

Within the `forloop` I would run an extra print the array to see the region taxonomy and it would display as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 420
            [name] => Connecticut
            [slug] => connecticut
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 420
            [taxonomy] => listings_region
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 419
            [count] => 1
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [1] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 419
            [name] => USA
            [slug] => usa
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 419
            [taxonomy] => listings_region
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 3
            [filter] => raw
        )

)
```

I need to find a way to put USA at the top because `[parent] => 0`.

It appears it's sorting it alphabetically instead.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$location = wp_get_post_terms($id, 'listings_region', array('orderby'=> 'parent'));
```